# Source UITextview from plist

Tags: ios, uitextview, plist

In Android development you can fill a `TextView` from an XML file without explicitly writing Java code to tell the view to get the string from said file by leaving the tag of the string in the XML file for the source of the text. Is there any similar ways to source text from a plist or an XML file to a `UITextView`without a line of Objective C code to do the interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is nothing like this built into the standard API for `UITextView`. But it wouldn't take much code to write a `UITextView` subclass that supported this feature. With a little extra work, your subclass could be used in a storyboard and populated without writing any further code.